# Auth::attempt() should only login when user has Admin role

Tags: php, performance, authentication, laravel, authorization

I have the following roles of users in my application.

- superuser
- admin
- moderator
- user

I want only the top 3 roles`('superuser', 'admin', 'moderator')` to login in to the web application. And the `'user'` can only login thro the mobile application. Pivot table is used for associating roles and users.

I used the below method to tackle the situation. ***I am not sure how efficient my solution is! Please help me to find a better way or improve this solution.***

**UsersController**

```
public function loginAction()
{

    if (User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->firstOrFail()->isPrivileged()) {

        if (Auth::attempt([
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            ],
            true)
        ) {
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('loginerror', 'Invalid Username or password');
}
```

**User Model**

```
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $privilege = ['superuser', 'admin', 'moderator'];

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasRole($name)
{
    if (!$this->has('roles')) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        if ($role->name == $name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getRolesCSV()
{
    $rolesCSV = '';
    $roles = $this->roles->toArray();
    $last = array_pop($roles);

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $rolesCSV = $rolesCSV . $role['name'] . ', ';
    }

    return ucwords($rolesCSV . $last['name']);
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isPrivileged()
{
    foreach ($this->privilege as $role) {
        if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AndrewRyno Thanks. I always have this feel that other programmers do way better than me. Lack of self confidence...